# How to create Solr 6 cores?

Tags: linux, solr, solr6

I've installed Solr 6 on a Digital Ocean ubuntu instance:

```
install_solr_service.sh solr-6.1.0.tgz
```

and verified that Solr is running. However, I cannot create any cores, either through the UI or at the command line. I've tried various different permutations of:

```
sudo ./solr create -c netest
```

including

```
sudo ./solr create -c netest -d /opt/solr/server/solr/configsets/basic_configs/conf/
```

but it always gives me:

```
ERROR: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'netest': Unable to create core [netest] Caused by: /var/solr/data/netest/data
```

If I create the directory in advance:

```
sudo mkdir /var/solr/data/netest/
sudo mkdir /var/solr/data/netest/data
sudo chown -R solr:solr /var/solr/data
```

when I rerun the create command I get:

> ERROR: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'netest': Unable to create core [netest] Caused by: Can't find resource 'solrconfig.xml' in classpath or '/var/solr/data/netest'

If I copy `solrconfig.xml` into the directory and run the command again I get:

> ERROR: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'netest': Unable to create core [netest] Caused by: Can't find resource 'schema.xml' in classpath or '/var/solr/data/netest'

and I'm stuck at this stage as google isn't helping me find where to get or create the schema.xml file.

Can anyone help?

Comment: The chown-line doesn't match the other lines - and is /var/solr owned by the solr user? (and otherwise empty when issuing the first create command?) .. and you can find [more about schema.xml](http://solr.pl/en/2010/08/16/what-is-schema-xml/) if you google 'schema.xml solr'

Comment: Thanks. The chown-line was a typo in the question. Yes, /var/solr is owned by the solr user, no it's not empty (data  log4j.properties logs  solr-8983.pid  solrconfig.xml). I'll take a look at the schema link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error CREATEing SolrCore 'gettingstarted': Unable to create core \[gettingstarted\] Caused by: /var/solr/data/gettingstarted/data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851416/error-createing-solrcore-gettingstarted-unable-to-create-core-gettingstarted)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this way

Navigate to `Solr/solr-6.1.0/server/solr/`

create new folder and name it **netest**.

copy conf folder from `Solr/solr-6.1.0/server/solr/configsets/basic_configs/` and paste it inside **netest** folder.

now you enter this command on terminal `sudo ./solr create -c netest`

This will create newcore with name netest using config files inside conf folder

hope this helps

Comment: i was also about to give that answer only !! Its kind of a mystery in Solr 6 :) . Vinod if we have to create cores like this only, then what is the use of rest call that claims to create cores dynamically . It cannot if we dont make a set up like this ?? what is your comment on that ?

Comment: @codechat `bin/solr create -c new_core` this command actually works. I mean I didn't create folder with name new_core with conf folder inside it. But I too got same error with `sudo` so I suggested to create folder with corename.   I am not sure if this error because of using superdo `sudo`.  Have to check about that , please update me if you get  information.

Comment: This works also for Solr 7.x, except that basic_config is now called _default

Comment: For me, copying folder conf from "C:\...\solr-8.9.0\solr-8.9.0\server\solr\configsets\sample_techproducts_configs" worked

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't use `root`, but `solr` user privileges to create Solr cores since data folder (e.g. `/var/solr/data`) is usually owned by `solr`. Secondly please note that provided `solr` shell script is still using the Solr Admin UI as the main starting point for administering Solr.

So try the following commands:

```
cd /opt/solr
sudo -u solr ./bin/solr create -c netest
sudo ls -la /var/solr/data
```

For any other problems, please double check that:

- Solr is accessible via Admin UI (e.g. `curl -s http://localhost:8983/solr/` or `links`).
- `jar` command is accessible (it is in your `PATH`).
- For syntax, run: `bin/solr --help` in your Solr HOME folder.

For troubleshooting, check your Solr logs (e.g. `/var/solr/logs/solr.log`).

Related: [SOLR-7826: Permission issues when creating cores with bin/solr as root user](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7826).

Answer (score 2):

Its permission issue, so try to create a new core using below command, and it will work!

```
sudo -u solr bin/solr create -c demo
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have created `schema.xml` and `solrconfig.xml` in your core directory, try *Add Core* from core admin page, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

./solr create_core -c netest -d basic_configs

Answer (score 0):

```
su - solr -c "/opt/solr/bin/solr create -c testcore -n 
data_driven_schema_configs"
```

This command works for me in solr 6.60 with the sudo user.