# Creating Core Directory with Bitnami Solr on Azure

Tags: linux, apache, azure, solr, bitnami

Sorry for this rudimentary question, but I am not a Linux guy at all and have never worked with Solr before.

I have deployed a new VM on Azure with the [Bitnami Solr 6.4 image](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/bitnami.apachesolr).

I am using the web admin UI to create a new core. It states that the instanceDir and the dataDir need to exist prior to creating the core. Upon attempting to create these directories, I am confronted with a Permission Denied issue.

`mkdir /opt/bitnami/apache-solr/server/solr/extremeledcore: permission denied`

It seems the owner of the `solr` directory is a user of `solr`, and only the owner is allowed to create directories.
[image: directory rights and owner]

But the problem is, I have no idea the credentials of user `solr`. I presume it is a default user created during the install. I have a different username when logging into the VM, let's call it `vmadmin`, which is how I login to the server using putty and FileZilla. And attempting to `mkdir` in either FileZilla or Putty, results in a `Permission Denied` error.

[image: Logged in as VMadmin in Putty getting error]

Note it is also a bit confusing that when I login as `vmadmin` in putty, the prompt shows `bitnami@SolrVM`, which I believe is typically in the format of `username@servername`...but I logged in as `vmadmin` not `bitnami`....but I digress.

The only other login credientials I am aware of are for the `solr` admin panel itself and that user name created by the solr install is simply `user`. So I have no idea how to login as `solr` or override the properties to allow my VM admin user to `mkdir`.

~Windows Guy in a Linux World

Answer (score 1):

The one that worked for me was:

```
sudo -u solr ./bin/solr create -c myCore
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following command:

```
 $solr_home bin/solr create_core -c extremeledcore
```

By using it, you should be able to create a Solr core.

Detailed documentation on how to create a core can be found here:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CoreAdmin+API#CoreAdminAPI-CREATE

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, we can use `sudo -i` to switch user to root, so you can mkdir and you will not receive error `permission denied`.

```
bitnami@jason:~$ sudo -i
root@jason:~# whoami
root
root@jason:~# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
root@jason:~#
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a Bitnami image, you need to use the following commands in order to create a new core in your instance:

`cd /opt/bitnami/apache-solr`

`sudo su solr -c './bin/solr create -c CORE-NAME'`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the only way I got it to work was to change the user permissions on the solr directory:
`bitnami@SolrVM:/opt/bitnami/apache-solr/server/solr$ sudo chmod -R ugo+rw <MY_CORE_NAME>`. Note the new core name folder did exist under `/opt/bitnami/apache-solr/server/solr/MY_CORE_NAME` as a result of the failed core create attempt.

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38430958/1135535), I then created copied the `/opt/bitnami/apache-solr/server/solr/configsets/basic_configs/conf` directory to my new core directory `/opt/bitnami/apache-solr/server/solr/MY_CORE_NAME/conf`. Then used the Solr Admin UI via the web browser to create the core.